# dictionary with custom ordering in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an available map-like data structure in python that supports custom ordering, insertion and deletion? I want to store (key,value) pairs where keys are int and values are object with many fields so that they are ordered by some particular fields of the value.

Comment: you can write any data structure you'd like. But I'm sure I'm following what your requirements are exactly

Comment: You can use an `OrderedDict`, that might serve your purposes better -- allows you to sort the way you want

Comment: @sshah98: Plain `dict` is insertion-ordered in modern Python (implementation detail of CPython/PyPy 3.6, language guarantee as of 3.7). `OrderedDict`'s only selling points are the `move_to_end`, a modified `popitem`, and order-sensitive equality comparisons. But it's still no good for arbitrary sorting, it's just a little friendlier on modifying the default insertion-based ordering.

Comment: This is really too underspecified to provide a useful answer. If  have a mapping of integers to values, what does `data[1]` mean? is that the second item of the sorted structure or the mapping from the key `1`? You'll need to tell us more about how you want to access the data and how the mapping vs order works. Does order only matter when iterating, of do you need to randomly access ordered items?

Answer (score 0):

i am settled with a dict of (key, val) and a priority queue of tuple (score, key)
where score is used for sorting and can be derived from the val object.